# Saving a record to a table from a form, which includes a subform, only after button click

Tags: vba, microsoft-access

I'm a newcomer to Access, so I haven't been able to figure this out yet. After Googling, I found the code below, but there are issues with it.

I have a bound form that includes a subform. I placed a button on the form that I want the user to **have** to click in order to save the record.

This code below does not save the record when the button is clicked. It does pop up a message box when I click into the subform, which is ok, but whether I "X" out of the box or click "ok" it still then saves the record.

Any help would be appreciated. Either modifying this code, or implementing completely different code.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim tfAllowSave As Boolean

Private Sub btnSave_Click()
   tfAllowSave = True
   If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   If tfAllowSave = False Then
      Cancel = False
      MsgBox "Do you want to save the record?"
   End If
   tfAllowSave = False
End Sub
```

Comment: There are several problems here. Clear the form rather than changing the dirty variable. You need to make the msgbox have a yes/no option, and then save that to a variable. You can then use an if statement to check if that variable = vbyes/vbno and do as you wish. For example if they click no, you would want cancel to =true

Comment: Thanks for your comments. If I scrap the code above and use the button wizard to handle new record, delete, and save, then it accomplishes most of what I need. I read that there is no way to keep the main form from saving when you click in a subform, while maintaining the info typed into the main form.

Comment: That is true, the second you click into the subform it will try and save the information on the main form. You either have to accept the save, or cancel it and clear the information on the main form. I've had the exact same problem!